# How can I make someone else group manager of a group I've created?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users

I created a few groups and populated them with users. I also selected an admin per group. I don't want to appear on the OG members view of the group anymore, therefore I want to remove myself from the group. I find this impossible.
Probably, because I'm the group manager. How can I change the group manager to that admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the author of the group node. Make it someone else than yourself.

Comment: Alright, nice and evil hack :) Somehow changes history, but very effective.

Comment: That's the way it has been since the dawn of OG. No hack ;)

Comment: Well but I do more than I actually want to do, I actually change the history of the created content.

Comment: You mean the updated date? Yes, it does change.

Comment: No I mean that although I have created the group node, it now appears like someone else has created it.

Comment: Where does it appear that way? What history are you talking about? Revisions?

Comment: If necessary, when creating groups, you can use Switch user from Devel module, become that user, and create the group.

Comment: Someone else looks at the group node and sees "Aha, UserB has created that Node". But it's not true. It was me who created it.

Comment: The Organic Groups concept is "organic", meaning that users themselves can create groups. Everything is built around that concept. So let them create their own groups or use Switch user. Mind you, users can also be groups nowadays ;)

Comment: Yes I know that, and that's a great concept, but it just happened that I used to be the leading person in that group and I'm not anymore. It seems impossible to give over complete control without changing history that way.